# php functions not updating the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, function

i have a question that im not able to find a workaround. i have the following :

```
db("select * from {$game}_stars where event_random = '11'");

$sn_sys = dbr();
if($sn_sys['event_random'] == 11) 

        dbn("update {$game}_stars set event_random = 6 where event_random = '11, metal = '583720', fuel='948372', star_name = 'SuperNova Remnant' where star_id = '$sn_sys[star_id]'");
        dbn("insert into {$game}_news (timestamp, headline, login_id) values (".time().",'The star in <b class=b1>system $sn_sys[star_id]</b> has exploded destroying everything in the system, and leaving a <b class=b1>Supernova Remnant</b> which is extremly rich in metals and fuel. All adjoining systems have also recieved generous quantities of minerals. We believe the SuperNova Remnant will turn into a <b>Blackhole</b> over due course.<font color=lime>- - - Science Institute of Sol - - -</font>','-11')");

        #take out non-eps.
        db2("select * from {$game}_ships where location = '$sn_sys[star_id]' && login_id !='1'");
        while ($ship_sn = dbr()) {
            if ($ship_sn['shipclass'] != 2) {
                dbn("insert into {$game}_messages (timestamp,sender_name,sender_id, login_id, text) values(".time().",'SuperNova','$ship_sn[login_id]','$ship_sn[login_id]','Your ship the <b class=b1>$ship_sn[ship_name]</b> was destroyed by an exploding star (<b>Supernova</b>) in system #<b>$ship_sn[location]</b>')");
                dbn("delete from {$game}_ships where ship_id = '$ship_sn[ship_id]'");
                dbn("insert into {$game}_news (timestamp, headline, login_id) values (".time().",'$ship_sn[login_name] lost a $ship_sn[class_name] to the SuperNova in system #<b>$ship_sn[location]<b>','$ship_sn[login_id]')");
            } else {
                dbn("insert into {$game}_messages (timestamp,sender_name,sender_id, login_id, text) values(".time().",'SuperNova','$ship_sn[login_id]','$ship_sn[login_id]','Your <b>Escape Pod</b> was near a star when it exploded. Fortunatly is was not hurt by the explosion, but was flung to a different system. Some well-wisher then brought you to system #1.')");
                dbn("update {$game}_users set location = '1' where ship_id = '$ship_sn[ship_id]'");
                dbn("update {$game}_ships set location = '1' where login_id = '$ship_sn[login_id]'");
            }
        }

        #take out non admin planets
        db2("select * from {$game}_planets where location = '$sn_sys[star_id]' && owner_id != '1'");

        while ($planet_sn = dbr2()) {
            dbn("insert into {$game}_messages (timestamp,sender_name,sender_id, login_id, text) values(".time().",'SuperNova','$planet_sn[owner_id]','$planet_sn[owner_id]','Your planet (<b class=b1>$planet_sn[planet_name]</b>) was oblterated by an exploding star (<b>Supernova</b>) in system #<b>$planet_sn[location]. It no longer excists, nor does anything that was on it.')");
            dbn("delete from {$game}_planets where planet_id = $planet_sn[planet_id]");
            dbn("insert into {$game}_news (timestamp, headline, login_id) values (".time().",'The planet $planet_sn[planet_name] was totally destroyed by the SuperNova in system #<b>$planet_sn[location]<b>','$planet_sn[owner_id]')");
        }

    #move users to sol or next ship
    db2("select * from {$game}_users where location = '$sn_sys[star_id]' && login_id > '3' && ship_id != 1");

    while($users = dbr2()) {
        db("select * from {$game}_ships where login_id = '$users[login_id]' && login_id != 1");

        if($other = dbr()) {
            dbn("update {$game}_users set ship_id = '$other[ship_id]', location = '$other[location]' where login_id = '$other[login_id]'");
            dbn("insert into {$game}_messages (timestamp,sender_name,sender_id, login_id, text) values(".time().",'SuperNova','$users[login_id]','$users[login_id]','Command was transfered to the <b class=b1>$other[ship_name]</b>.')");
        } else {
            dbn("insert into {$game}_messages (timestamp,sender_name,sender_id, login_id, text) values(".time().",'SuperNova','$users[login_id]','$users[login_id]','You ejected in an escape pod.')");
            dbn("insert into {$game}_ships (ship_name, login_id, login_name, shipclass, class_name, location, point_value) values('Escape Pod','$users[login_id]','$users[login_name]',2,'Escape Pod','1',5)");

            dbn("select * from {$game}_ships where login_id = '$users[login_id]'");

            $ship_id = dbr();
            dbn("update {$game}_users set location = '1', ship_id ='$ship_id[ship_id]' where login_id = '$users[login_id]'");
        }
    }


        db("select * from {$game}_stars where star_id = '$sn_sys[star_id]'");

        $link = dbr();
        $link_1 = $link['link_1'];
        $link_2 = $link['link_2'];
        $link_3 = $link['link_3'];
        $link_4 = $link['link_4'];
        $link_5 = $link['link_5'];
        $link_6 = $link['link_6'];

        dbn("update {$game}_stars set fuel= fuel +'103482', metal= metal+'12354' where star_id != '1' && star_id != 0 && star_id = '$link_1'");
        dbn("update {$game}_stars set fuel= fuel +'95444', metal= metal+'56484' where star_id != '1' && star_id != 0 && star_id = '$link_2'");
        dbn("update {$game}_stars set fuel= fuel +'74452', metal= metal+'46877' where star_id != '1' && star_id != 0 && star_id = '$link_3'");
        dbn("update {$game}_stars set fuel= fuel +'37353', metal= metal+'106210' where star_id != '1' && star_id != 0 && star_id = '$link_4'");
        dbn("update {$game}_stars set fuel= fuel +'74523', metal= metal+'68757' where star_id != '1' && star_id != 0 && star_id = '$link_5'");
        dbn("update {$game}_stars set fuel= fuel +'63452', metal= metal+'83254' where star_id != '1' && star_id != 0 && star_id = '$link_6'");

        print "<br />Supernova in $sn_sys[star_id] went bang.<br />";
}
```

this script is set so it inserts a message in the database with the event specs and , of course to run the queries.

Now, only the

```
insert into {$game}_news
```

seems to get processed and everything else is not.

here are my db functions

```
function db($string) {
    global $query;
    $query = mysql_query($string);
}

function dbr() 
{
    global $query;
    $fetched = $query->fields;
    return $fetched;
}
function db2($string) {
    global $query2;
    $query2 = mysql_query($string);
}

function dbr2() 
{
    global $query2;
    $fetched2 = $query2->fields;
    return $fetched2;
}
```

function dbn

```
function dbn($string) {
    mysql_query($string);
}
```

Any ideas on why and any possible solutions?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: i added it to the question. sorry about that.

Comment: they use raw mysql functions - will be easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to change `'$ship_sn[ship_id]'` with `'{$ship_sn[ship_id]}'` ?

Comment: While he is at it he could change `'$sn_sys[star_id]'` to `'{$sn_sys[star_id]}'`

Comment: @Tray it's verry important to mark array access with `{}` because else something like '$var[1]' would evaluate to 'array[1]' because $var is an array and [1] won't be evaluated as an array access

Comment: that gives me an 'undefined constant'

Comment: ah yeah is see. you try to access the $star_id of $sn_sys array.

Comment: every time  i try that it gives me the same error undefined constant.

Comment: @Trey did you follow @ITroubs suggestion changing {$ship_sn["ship_id"]} to '{$sn_sys[$star_id]}' ?

Answer (score 0):

`while ($ship_sn = dbr2()) {` - i think it helps. But i think you should rewrite your functions.

Comment: And.. can be wrong, but mysql doesn't understand `&&` - use `AND`